# How to make a border on a video stream using opencv and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am learning opencv with python and i have got my video running perfectly using opencv but i want to make a border on the video . This is what i have tried so far but it didn't worked.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(1)
waitTime=50
while (1):


    ret,frame=cam.read()
#cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame,1000,1000,1000,1000,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[0,255,255])
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame,1000,1000,1000,1000,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[0,200,200])
    #cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',draw)
    if  cv2.waitKey(waitTime) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
            break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `imshow` after `copyMakeBorder`, and put the *image with border* in a variable:

```
frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame,1000,1000,1000,1000,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[0,200,200])
cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you make the border too large (`1000`) and that you didn't specify to which image you copy to. It should go like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(1)
waitTime=50

while (1):
    ret,frame=cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    borderedFrame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[0,200,200])
    cv2.imshow("bordered frame", borderedFrame)
    if  cv2.waitKey(waitTime) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```